# Enterprise Library for Logging to Flat File Trace Listener

Tags: enterprise-library, error-logging

What kind of permission needs to be given to the Error.log file in the server (running IIS 7.5) so that errors are written to the Error.log file?

I have created a directory named ErrorLog and set up the listener in web.config like below.

Answer (score 2):

The windows identity in play (depends on how you authenticate)

```
var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;  //normally this reverts to Thread.CurrentPrincipal, but can be changed
return principal.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
var windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            if (windowsIdentity != null)
            {
                return windowsIdentity.Name;
            }
```

The Executing windows identity Will need create permission in directory and write permission to the file specified in your EL config.
You can place file anywhere you like using config.  Default for file without path is Start project directory containing assembly dll.

See In IIS  the **Application Pool** used by the website. The pool determines the windows Identity. See the **advanced settings tab for the Pool**.  The identity approach to be used is defined here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your configuration example, but..

I find that it is best not to use Flat File outside of development. The Event Log or Database listeners are more suitable for a web application in production.

If you must use Flat File, you will need to give the account (for the application pool that is assigned to the web application) write access to the directory that the file should be created in. By default I think that is the web application's bin directory, unless you include a path in the file name in your configuration.

Comment: I like to use the FlatFileTraceListener for the errors special source (assuming permissions are properly configured) since I want a different trace listener than the one that has failed and I also want a simple trace listener that has less dependencies (e.g. database, network, event log, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on what context your app in operating in. The app pool thread is responsible for writing the log so give the read/write folder permissions for the same identity as your app pool. I think this is NETWORKSERVICE by default.